# Spring Repositories with different profiles

Tags: spring-profiles, spring-repositories

I have two different profiles and want to have two different repositories for this profiles. But it's repositories for one entity and it's just have different conditions in query.

I try to do this:

It's my base interface for repository:

```
public interface RepositoryBaseInterface extends CrudRepository<MyEntity, Long> {
    List<MyEntity> getEntities();
}
```

And I have two profiles repository:

```
@Repository
@Profile("profile1)
public interface ProfileRepository extends RepositoryBaseInterface {
    @Query("My query 1")
    List<MyEntity> getEntities();
}
```

And another one:

```
@Repository
@Profile("profile2)
public interface ProfileRepository2 extends RepositoryBaseInterface {
    @Query("My query 2")
    List<MyEntity> getEntities();
}
```

I have class when I use this repository:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgConstructor
public class UseRepository{

  RepositoryBaseInterface repository;

  public List<MyEntity> getMyEntities() {
     return repository.getEntities();
  }
}
```

I have expected when I have one of two active profiles it will be chosen one of two ProfilesRepositories but I see that only RepositoryBaseInterface is using and I recieved error

```
Error creating bean with name RepositoryBeanInterface
IllegalArgumentException, No property getEntities found for type MyEntity
```

**How can I fix this and use one or another repository in dependency of my active profile?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understood my mistake. Our Base Interface ought to don't have any extends.  But its implementation ought to.

So I have

```
    public interface RepositoryBaseInterface {
       List<MyEntity> getEntities();
    }
```

And two Profile interface:

```
    @Repository
    @Profile("profile1)
    public interface ProfileRepository extends RepositoryBaseInterface, CrudRepository<MyEntity, Long> {

      @Query("My query 1")
      List<MyEntity> getEntities();
}

    @Repository
    @Profile("profile2)
    public interface ProfileRepository2 extends RepositoryBaseInterface, CrudRepository<MyEntity, Long> {

      @Query("My query 2")
      List<MyEntity> getEntities();
}
```